# Dropdownlist get value out ddl and use it above

Tags: java, servlets, drop-down-menu, onchange

I'm trying to make a dropdownlist of the months. When the user select a month, the javascript fills the setter with the chosen value. Now I want to use that value above. So I made a form around my select with the action 'Onchange' and use the getMaand to calls the chosen month.

Is there something wrong with the form? Because when I put this in comment, I get the dropdownlist with the months, when I put it in code, he prints every month in one line.

I'm not an expert in Java, is it correct to use Onchange in the form and in the select?

```
    int m = -1;
    HTMLCode += "<form onchange=\"window.open('availability.jsp?user=99&clickeddate="+dateFormat.format(today.getTime())+"&month=" + avail.getMaand() + "','_self')\"";
    HTMLCode += "<select onchange='javascript:setMonth(\"" + m + "\");'>";
    for (m=today.get(Calendar.MONTH); m<12; m++){    
    if(month == m)
    HTMLCode += "<option value='" + m + "' selected>" + maand_voluit[m]+ "</option>";
    else
    HTMLCode += "<option value='" + m + "'>" + maand_voluit[m] + "</option>";
    }
    HTMLCode += "</select>";
    HTMLCode += "</form>";
```

Kind regards

Comment: what exactly you are using exactly ? Servlets? JSP? SWing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining Form and Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011665/combining-form-and-select)

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a value for month

Try this:

```
int month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
HTMLCode += "<form onchange=\"window.open('availability.jsp?   user=99&clickeddate="+dateFormat.format(today.getTime())+"&month=" + avail.getMaand() + "','_self')\"";
HTMLCode += "<select onchange='javascript:setMonth(\"" + m + "\");'>";
for (int m=0; m<12; m++){    
if(month == m)
HTMLCode += "<option value='" + m + "' selected>" + maand_voluit[m]+ "</option>";
else
HTMLCode += "<option value='" + m + "'>" + maand_voluit[m] + "</option>";
}
HTMLCode += "</select>";
HTMLCode += "</form>";
```