# Combining Form and Select

Tags: java, forms, servlets, select, action

when I put the form in comment, it works. 
But I need a form because I need to call the action "onclick". 
With this code, it prints the values in one line.

Now he prints: AprilMayJuneJulyAugustSeptemberOctoberNovemberDecember in one long String. 
It must be in the dropdownlist.

Please need some help?

```
    HTMLCode += "<form name='month' onclick=\"window.open('availability.jsp?user=99&clickeddate="+dateFormat.format(today.getTime())+"&month=" + avail.getMaand() + "','_self')\"";
    HTMLCode += "<select onchange='javascript:setMonth(\"" + m + "\");'>";
    for (m=today.get(Calendar.MONTH); m<12; m++){    
    if(month == m)
    HTMLCode += "<option value='" + m + "' selected>" + maand_voluit[m]+ "</option>";
    else
    HTMLCode += "<option value='" + m + "'>" + maand_voluit[m] + "</option>";
    }
    HTMLCode += "</select>";
    HTMLCode += "</form>";
```

Comment: what is the question??

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. Please give information about the context in your question.

Comment: why don't you use JSPs?

Comment: I copied the problem in the question. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have missed `>` in your form tag:

```
HTMLCode += "<form name='month' 
   onclick=\"window.open('availability.jsp?
   user=99&clickeddate="+dateFormat.format(today.getTime())+"&month=" + avail.getMaand() +
   "','_self')\">";

                ^
                |
                |
             This one
```

So that does not make up valid html and hence you get everything on a single line rather than what you expected.

Also, a tip, use JSPs as they are neat and readable.

Comment: Stupid mistake..thanks Abu. I will set your answer as correct in 5 minutes. Thanks